# Install OpenCV 3 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python3, opencv

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and I want to install OpenCV 3 on it.

How can I install OpenCV for Python 3 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 17.10 and above:**

`python3-opencv` package is available in Official Ubuntu Repositories.

So you can install this package with this command easily (without any need to pip or any other ways):

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

---

**Additional information :**

As this package is available in `universe` repositories of Ubuntu, so this repositories should be active on your machine (That's active by default) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 repository seems to have Opencv 3.1, which is quite old. My OpenCV 3.3 PPA is here: https://launchpad.net/~timsc/+archive/ubuntu/opencv-3.3